# Auto populate field depending on option selected

Tags: javascript

I want to auto fill the "Unit Price" input with the products "data-price" when a user picks a product without reloading the page. Is this possible?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p>Testers<br>
        <select id="productOne" name="productOne">
          <option data-price="1249.99" value="1">PRO Battery Tester</option>
          <option data-price="444.99" value="2">MDX335P</option>
          <option data-price="494.99" value="3">MDX645</option>
          <option data-price="694.99" value="4">MDX645P</option>
          <option data-price="694.99" value="5">MDX655</option>
          <option data-price="899.99" value="6">MDX655P</option>
          <option data-price="949.99" value="7">MDX655P Start Stop</option>
        </select></p>
        <p>Chargers<br>
        <select id="productTwo" name="productTwo">
          <option data-price="1249.99" value="1">PRO 60</option>
          <option data-price="1249.99" value="2">MXTS 70/50 EU-K</option>
          <option data-price="333.33" value="3">MXS 25EC UK</option>
          <option data-price="199.99" value="4">MXS 10EC UK</option>
          <option data-price="633.33" value="5">MXTS 40 UK</option>
          <option data-price="266.66" value="6">MXS 25 UK</option>
          <option data-price="266.66" value="7">MXT 14 UK</option>
          <option data-price="175.83" value="8">MXT 4.0 UK</option>
        </select></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p>Quantity<br><input type="number" name="productOneQ" min="0" step="any"  value="<?php if(!is_null($productOneQ)) { echo $productOneQ; } ?>"></p>
        <p>Quantity<br><input id="productTwoQ" type="number" name="productTwoQ" min="0" step="any"  value="<?php if(!is_null($productTwoQ)) { echo $productTwoQ; } ?>"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p>Unit Price<br><input id="productOneP" type="number" name="productOneP" min="0" step="any"  value="<?php if(!is_null($productOneP)) { echo $productOneP; } ?>"></p>
        <p>Unit Price<br><input id="productTwoP" type="number" name="productTwoP" min="0" step="any"  value="<?php if(!is_null($productTwoP)) { echo $productTwoP; } ?>"></p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
          <p><span id="productOneT" class="total right">TOTAL: £<?php echo number_format($productOneTotal = $productOneP*$productOneQ, 2, '.', ','); ?></span></p>
          <p><span id="productTwoT" class="total right">TOTAL: £<?php echo number_format($productTwoTotal = $productTwoP*$productTwoQ, 2, '.', ','); ?></span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wanna code using JQuery??

Comment: JQuery or vanilla, I'm unsure how to do this

Comment: try Jquery!! :)

Comment: Try angular, knockout, etc.

Comment: Yes but how do I do this in JQuery?

Comment: i am not clear about your question please add additional information afterward ill solve your problem or chat with me

Comment: I recommend you to use Vanilla Js instead of Jquery.  It's lighter faster and you get a better understanding of what is done and what can be achieved.  Just FYI>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto fill field depending on the option selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737879/auto-fill-field-depending-on-the-option-selected)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use only javascript?
Ok, take a look at my solution;

The HTML is like;

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                        <p>Chargers<br>
                        <select id="xyz" name="productTwo">
                          <option data-price="p1" value="chargerOne">PRO 60</option>
                          <option data-price="p2"  value="chargerTwo">MXTS 70/50 EU-K</option>
                          <option data-price="p3"  value="chargerThree">MXS 25EC UK</option>
                          <option data-price="p4"  value="chargerFour">MXS 10EC UK</option>
                          <option data-price="p5"  value="chargerFive">MXTS 40 UK</option>
                          <option data-price="p6"  value="chargerSix">MXS 25 UK</option>
                          <option data-price="p7"  value="chargerSeven">MXT 14 UK</option>
                          <option data-price="p8"  value="chargerEight">MXT 4.0 UK</option>
                        </select></p>
                    </div>

 <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <p>Quantity<br><input id="q" type="number" name="productTwoQ" min="0" step="any"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <p>Unit Price<br><input id="p" type="number" name="productTwoP" min="0" step="any"></p>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                          <p><span class="total right" id="t"></span></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Now the js;

```
$("#xyz").change(function(){

    $("#q").val($(this).val());
    $("#p").val($(this).attr("data-price"));

    $("#t").html("Total : "+($(this).val()*$(this).attr("data-price")))
})
```

Comment: Any error showing? Include the jquery library or CDN.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with jQuery:

```
$('select[name="productTwo"]').change(function() {
     $('input[name="productTwoP"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Note: the values of your select options has to be an integer, if that is not possible you have to change the input type of productTwoP to text instead of number.

```
<select name="productTwo">
                              <option value="60">PRO 60</option>
                              <option value="70">MXTS 70/50 EU-K</option>
                              <option value="25">MXS 25EC UK</option>
                              <option value="chargerFour">MXS 10EC UK</option>
                              <option value="chargerFive">MXTS 40 UK</option>
                              <option value="chargerSix">MXS 25 UK</option>
                              <option value="chargerSeven">MXT 14 UK</option>
                              <option value="chargerEight">MXT 4.0 UK</option>
                            </select>
```

or add the price as an attribute e.g.

```
<option data-price="60" value="chargerOne"></option>
```

and read the data-price value with `$(this).data('price')`