# Auto-fill in textbox based on select option

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.1

I am creating a table which when "Item" is selected, the description will be filled automatically based on select option.

I have referred to some other links like:

[Auto fill field depending on the option selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737879/auto-fill-field-depending-on-the-option-selected)

https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/adg9s5/make_a_text_box_automatically_fill_depending_on/

but none of them answer my question.

Here's my script

```
$('#item').change(function(e){
     var element = $(this).find('option:selected'); 
     var desc = element.attr("Description");
    $('#Description').text(desc);
    console.log(desc)

});
```

This is for the item

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="item" name="item">
<option value="" disabled selected>None</option>
@foreach ($deliveryitems as $items)
<option  value="{{$items->Id}}">{{$items->Item_Code}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

This is for the description

```
<input type="text" class="Description form-control" name="Description" id="Description" readonly>
```

This is my controller

```
$deliveryitems = DB::table('inventories')
        ->leftJoin('deliveryitem','inventories.Id','=','deliveryitem.inventoryId')
        ->select('inventories.Id','deliveryitem.formId','inventories.Item_Code','inventories.Description','inventories.Unit','deliveryitem.Qty_request')
        ->get();
```

How to auto fill in the item description based on the item selected from the select options?

Comment: there is no `Description` attribute for `option` element

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks for your attention sir,
I have tried both .data("Description") and .attr() but both shows "undefined" in the console.
In fact, I have "Description" in my database.The error comes from here but I dont know how to solve it.

I have tired .val() and .text() too, both do not retrieve the output desired.

Comment: You have to add the attribute to the option element ... In the same way u added value attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method is using to update the text content of the element, for the input element, there is no text content. To update its value you can use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$('#Description').val(desc);
```

In addition to that, there is no `Description` attribute for the `option` element so you have to add the attribute in the same way `value` property added.

```
<option  value="{{$items->Id}}" Description="{{$items->Description}}">{{$items->Item_Code}}</option>
```

```js
$('#item').change(function(e) {
  var element = $(this).find('option:selected');
  var desc = element.attr("Description");
  $('#Description').val(desc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select2" id="item" name="item">
  <option value="" disabled selected>None</option>
  <option value="1" Description="a">1</option>
  <option value="2" Description="b">2</option>
  <option value="3" Description="c">3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="Description form-control" name="Description" id="Description" readonly>
```

---

It's always better to use [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute for the custom attribute.

PHP :

```
<option  value="{{$items->Id}}" data-description="{{$items->Description}}">{{$items->Item_Code}}</option>
```

JQuery :

```
$('#item').change(function(e){
     var element = $(this).find('option:selected'); 
     var desc = element.data("description");
    $('#Description').val(desc);
    console.log(desc)
});
```

```js
$('#item').change(function(e) {
  var element = $(this).find('option:selected');
  var desc = element.data("description");
  $('#Description').val(desc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select2" id="item" name="item">
  <option value="" disabled selected>None</option>
  <option value="1" data-description="a">1</option>
  <option value="2" data-description="b">2</option>
  <option value="3" data-description="c">3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="Description form-control" name="Description" id="Description" readonly>
```